# How do I create new journal template in Sharelatex?

Tags: templates, sharelatex, journal-publishing, journal

How do I create a new template for scientific journals in sharelatex?  I am trying to write my thesis but the template for my university is not present in the given sample templates.

Comment: Can you restate your question more clearly? I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: Are there any news here? I am confused as well, you are asking for generating templates for scientific journals, next you want to write a thesis. The question is, in its current state, unclear.

Comment: It sounds like there is no ready to use template for your university on ShareLaTeX? If that is the case have a google about and tell the ShareLaTeX support if you find one, they will add it to the site.